# I cannot use my state properly it is showing undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

[This is the error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZEZ7.png)Here it is showing me error that variable is not defined how can i fix this is there any method which i can use?

```
 const [indication, setindication] = React.useState({
    venous: "",
    flutter: "",
    heartValve: "",
    peripheral: "",
    antibody: "",
    other: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name: key, value } = event.target;
    if (key === venous) setindication({ ...indication, venous: value });
    else if (key === flutter) setindication({ ...indication, flutter: value });
    else if (key === heartValve)
      setindication({ ...indication, heartValve: value });
    else if (key === peripheral)
      setindication({ ...indication, peripheral: value });
    else if (key === antibody)
      setindication({ ...indication, antibody: value });
    else if (key === other) setindication({ ...indication, other: value });
    else setindication({ ...indication, [key]:"" });
  };
```

Where here this is the type of condition i have use where i want to apply it in my checkbox if anyone can help me this problem will be really helpful.

```
     <FormGroup>
                <FormControlLabel
                  value={indication.venous}
                  name="venous"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  control={
                    <Checkbox  />
                  }
                  label={
                    <Typography fontSize={20}>
                      Venous Thromboembolism (VTE)
                    </Typography>
                  }
                  labelPlacement="start"
                />
              </FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Still not sure if I fully understand the desired results, but if the preferred `indication` state is an array of selected values, such as `["venous"]`, `["venous", "other"]`, etc., here is a possible example.

Simplified live demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hocqen?file=src/App.js)

Define the state as `[]` array and modify the event handler to fill the array:

```
const [indication, setindication] = React.useState([]);

const handleChange = (event) =>
  setindication((prev) =>
    prev.includes(event.target.name)
      ? prev.filter((item) => item !== event.target.name)
      : [...prev, event.target.name]
  );
```

Because `indication` is an array only for selected values now, the data of the options need to be be saved in another `const` or it could come from props:

```
const optionsData = {
  venous: "",
  flutter: "",
  heartValve: "",
  peripheral: "",
  antibody: "",
  other: "",
};
```

**Original**

Since the `value` of `FormControlLabel` is bind with `indication.venous`, it seems that it would always be `""` empty string no matter if the `Checkbox` is checked.

Provided that this component looks like a `Checkbox`, perhaps the intended result is to save which options are checked (`true` or `false`)?

If so, perhaps the event handler could set `event.target.checked` as the new value, such as:

```
const handleChange = (event) =>
  setindication((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
  }));
```

A quick demo hopefully could help to visualize: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xzcssx?file=src/App.js)

Comment: Hello john actually my intention here is to store the check data before it was showing empty but whenever i check for example venous it should be stored. That is my intension.

Comment: @Shaiban What's the _check data_ and how should it be stored, also how was _showing empty_ looking like, if I may?

Comment: antibody: "" flutter: ""
heartValve: ""
other: ""
peripheral: ""
venous: "" It was showing this way. Now i want whenever i check mark it should show me selected value.

Comment: @Shaiban Thanks for the feedback, did you mean `indication` should ideally be one value such as just `venous` when it is selected? If not, what might the desired value look like?

Comment: Yes whenever I select venous the backend should be able to know that i have selected venous

Comment: @Shaiban How should it support multiple selects? The current solution in the answer will make `indication` be `{antibody: "" flutter: "" heartValve: "" other: "" peripheral: "" venous: true}` when `venous` is selected, and it seems to be already indicating the selected options. Would it work if it makes it `{antibody: "" flutter: "" heartValve: "" other: "" peripheral: "" venous: "selected"}`? Or perhaps an array of selected options is preferred, like `["venous"]`, `["venous", "other"]`, etc.?

Comment: Array prefered selection im looking for can you help me with that. And brother i have another doubt please help me with that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74981766/why-i-cannot-select-my-radio-button-what-mistake-im-facing?noredirect=1#comment132320777_74981766)

Answer (score 0):

The Variable `key` looks like should be string. Try this:

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name: key, value } = event.target;
    if (key === "venous") setindication({ ...indication, venous: value });
    else if (key === "flutter") setindication({ ...indication, flutter: value });
    else if (key === "heartValve")
      setindication({ ...indication, heartValve: value });
    else if (key === "peripheral")
      setindication({ ...indication, peripheral: value });
    else if (key === "antibody")
      setindication({ ...indication, antibody: value });
    else if (key === "other") setindication({ ...indication, other: value });
    else setindication({ ...indication, [key]:"" });
  };
```

Comment: it is giving me desired output but just asking what will difference if i will be using onChange={handleChange} inside checkbox component.?

Comment: In that case, the `handleChange` function will be triggered only if the `checkbox` component is changed.

Comment: Sorry this will be last question.. Is there any alternate and more convenient method than this one it will be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean how to simplify the handle change function? Yes, you can check out the [computed property](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-computed-property/). Eg. `setindication({ ...indication, [key]: value });`

Comment: Hello idk why but array is showing empty it is showing no value how can i fix it? Thank you