# why i cannot select my radio button what mistake im facing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

[This is the output...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFjaK.png)

Here I want to use radio button but i cannot select it can someone tell me what problem im facing it will be great help..

```
 const [value, setValue] = React.useState({
    yes:"",
    no:"",
    idk:"",
  });
  const handleChange=(e)=>{
    const{name:key,value} =e.target;
    if(key==="yes") setValue({...value,yes:value});
    else if(key==="no") setValue({...value,no:value});
    else if(key==="idk") setValue({...value,idk:value});
    else setValue({...DonutLargeSharp,[key]:""});
  }
```

This my return code can someone help me and explanation will also be grateful.

```
<FormControl>
    <RadioGroup
        aria-labelledby="demo-controlled-radio-buttons-group"
        name="controlled-radio-buttons-group"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}>
        <FormControlLabel
        value="yes"
        name="Yes"
        control={<Radio onChange={handleChange}/>}
        label="Yes"/>
        <FormControlLabel
        value="no"
        name="no"
        control={<Radio onChange={handleChange} />}
        label="No"/>
        <FormControlLabel
        value="idk"
        name="idk"
        control={<Radio onChange={handleChange} />}
        label="I do not know"/>
    </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
```

Here I want to select radio button but idk why i cannot do it maybe im bad in react (especially programming)

Comment: Could you create a CodeSandbox with your code snippet reproducing the issue you're having please. Reason for asking is that it's hard to determine which libraries you are using

Comment: Im using mui library

Answer (score 1):

No use over complicated your useState.

Simply do the following:

```
 const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (e) => setValue(e.target.value)
   

 <RadioGroup
        aria-labelledby="demo-controlled-radio-buttons-group"
        name="controlled-radio-buttons-group"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <FormControlLabel
          value="yes"
          name="Yes"
          control={<Radio onChange={handleChange} />}
          label="Yes"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="no"
          name="No"
          control={<Radio onChange={handleChange} />}
          label="No"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="idk"
          name="IDK"
          control={<Radio onChange={handleChange} />}
          label="I do not know"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
```

Result:

[image]